# C++ Swapping Member Arrays and Associated Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, swap

If I have a class containing a member array with pointers at each end, for example,

```
int mArray[5];
int *mStart = mArray;
int *mEnd = mArray + 5;
```

and I swap that class, say in my standard assignment operator using `std::swap(mArray, other.mArray)`, what happens to the pointers in the process?

This is a very contrived example, but in my program, if I swap just the array, the assignment operator works as intended, and if I try to swap all three member variables, it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: swapping objects doesn't (shouldn't) affect static data members simply because **static data members are not associated with any object**. Without knowing more about the semantics of your case, we can't answer more than this. And this smells like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: please provide a [MCVE] without it your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Contrive a *simple* example that compiles and runs and it will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you change the values stored in `mArray`, the array is still at the same address. So the pointers continue to be correct.

If you swap the pointer values with another object, the pointers in one object will then point to the array of the other object. Not going to work very well!

Instead of storing a pointer, you could do like the standard containers and have a `begin` member returning a pointer/iterator to the data.

```
int* begin()
{ return mArray; }
```

And likewise for `end()`.

Comment: I'm definitely aware that using iterators are good practice. Great advice!

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming these are not actually *static* members, but that you mean that they're not dynamically allocated.)

When you swap the arrays, the arrays don't move; only their contents are swapped.
(Arrays are not pointers.)

The reason it doesn't work if you swap the pointers is that the pointers then point into the array member of their "original" object.
If you don't swap them, they keep pointing into the array they were created from.

Ilustrating example:

Starting point:

```
Object A: mArray starts at 0x1000; mStart is 0x1000; mEnd is 0x1014
Object B: mArray starts at 0x2000; mStart is 0x2000; mEnd is 0x2014
```

After `swap` without pointer-swapping:

```
Object A: mArray starts at 0x1000; mStart is 0x1000; mEnd is 0x1014
Object B: mArray starts at 0x2000; mStart is 0x2000; mEnd is 0x2014
```

After `swap` with pointer-swapping:

```
Object A: mArray starts at 0x1000; mStart is 0x2000; mEnd is 0x2014
Object B: mArray starts at 0x2000; mStart is 0x1000; mEnd is 0x1014
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm still new to this, and I assumed that std::swap treated the array as a pointer and would swap it just like it would a regular pointer. It's nice to know that STL treats arrays as objects, not pointers. Thanks!